# Conditional statement not loading style sheets

Tags: html, internet-explorer

This is one of those rare occasions that I have had to use conditional statements in order to correct problems with IE. I am using IE8 and need to have a stylesheet for IE and one for FF and other browsers. I cannot see why this statement would not load the correct style sheet? I have put a simple message in a paragraph but neither message is being output. Can someone tell me how I would go about debugging this as my knowledge of conditional statements is zilch. I have put the statement in the head part of the html and all paths are correct. Thanks

```
<!--[if !IE]>

<link href="/sample/admin/css/menu/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<p style="color: blue; font-size:18px;">You are NOT using IE</p>

<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]>

<link href="/sample/admin/css/menu/css/ie_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<p style="color: blue; font-size:18px;">You are using IE</p>

<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use the second conditional:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link href="/sample/admin/css/menu/css/ie_layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
<![endif]-->
```

The first one isn't necessary.

To check if it is behing called, change (for example) the `body`, adding some background color; you should see it straight away. Also make sure the file path is correct.

Also, your `p` is behing inputted before the `<body>`? (I mean, you are adding the CSS at the `<head>`, correct?)

P.S. note that these type of conditional statements only work when using IE, that's why the first statement is unnecessary and won't output the message when viewed on a browser different than IE.

Comment: I have taken your suggestion and included background colour and removed the !IE statement. However, in the source code under BODY, I see this: <P style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: blue; COLOR: white; FONT-SIZE: 18px">You are using IE</P> but I cannot see it on the page. Thanks

Comment: Also, is there a way to stop inheriting from the layout.css?

Comment: @bollo the inheritance can only be "stoped" if you re-define the other classes in your IE specific css, ortherwise they will be used. The other solution would be via javascript to add or remove stylesheets.